# Making a clock with words

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to make a clock that outputs the current time differently depending on what time it is. Some examples are:

- If the time is 11:30 am, it should print 'It is half past Eleven Am'
- If the time is 11:50 - 11:59 am, it should print 'It is soon Twelve Am'

The code as it currently is looks like this:

```
from time import *
from num2words import num2words as n2w

Soon = [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
HalfPast = [30]
JustAfter = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

curr_time = strftime('%H:%M:%S', localtime())
curr_time_str = curr_time.split(':')
standard_phrase = "It's "
special_word = 'Nope'
ampm = strftime('%p', localtime())
ampm = ampm.lower()
ampm = ampm.title()
def check_time():
    for x in curr_time_str[1]:
        if int(x) in Soon:
            special_word = 'soon '
        elif int(x) in HalfPast:
            special_word = 'half past '
        elif int(x) in JustAfter:
            special_word = 'just after '
        else:
            pass
    return special_word

if check_time() != 'Nope':
    print(standard_phrase + check_time() + n2w(int(curr_time_str[0])).title() + ' ' + ampm)
elif check_time() == 'Nope':
    print(standard_phrase + n2w(int(curr_time_str[0])) + ':' + n2w(int(curr_time_str[1])))
else:
    exit()
```

I know it isn't the best code, but it looks like this for debugging.

Comment: That clock looks awesome! Now, what's your problem with it? What can't you figure out?

Comment: It outputs the same string everytime: 'It is just after Eleven Am'. I can't figure out why.

Comment: "11:59 am" is NOT soon 12am, but 12pm!

Comment: True, but the most important thing right now is getting it to work at all.

Comment: Well, what is your local time right now?

Comment: 11:58 am, I'm on PST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually pretty simple. Let’s see what’s going on:

As I’m writing this, this is my local value of `curr_time_str`:

```
>>> curr_time_str
['19', '57', '05']
```

Now, in `check_time` you are looking at `curr_time_str[1]`:

```
>>> curr_time_str[1]
'57'
```

That is a string; and you are actually looping over that string:

```
>>> for x in curr_time_str[1]:
        print(x)

5
7
```

So you get `5` and `7`. And both of those are in `JustAfter`, so you return `'just after '`.

And this actually happens for every number, because after all, if you only look at a single digit, you’re always below 10, and as such always inside `JustAfter`. So what you tried to do instead is look at the whole value of `curr_time_str[1]`:

```
def check_time():
    x = int(curr_time_str[1])
    if x in Soon:
        special_word = 'soon '
    elif x in HalfPast:
        special_word = 'half past '
    elif x in JustAfter:
        special_word = 'just after '
    return special_word
```